# How do I pass parameters between components in a React switch statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Currently I have a React component as follows:

```
export default function Company() {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  const [lookupData, setLookupData] = useState();
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const ticker = queryParams.get("ticker");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const lookupPromise = getLookupData(ticker);
    lookupPromise.then((data) => {
      setLookupData(data);
    });
  }, []);
  
  return lookupData ? (
    <>
      <h2>{lookupData.data.title}</h2>
      <ul class="leftNav">
        <li class="mainList">
          <a href="/Company/Overview">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mainList">Financials</li>
        <li class="indentList">
          <a href="/Company/KeyFinancials">Key Financials</a>
        </li>
        <li class="indentList">
          <a href="/Company/IncomeStatement">Income Statement</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="body">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path={`${path}/Overview`}>
              <Overview cik={lookupData.data.cik} />
            </Route>
            <Route path={`${path}/KeyFinancials`}>
              <KeyFinancials cik={lookupData.data.cik} />
            </Route>
            <Route path={`${path}/IncomeStatement`}>
              <IncomeStatement cik={lookupData.data.cik} />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path={`${path}/`}>
              <Redirect to={`${path}/Overview`} />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </>
  ) : "waiting for lookup data";
}
```

In each of the components, I use the cik to get a bunch more data. Right now it loads the overview in (using the cik) correctly (since that's the default component). However, if I switch components or refresh the page, the cik goes into the component as null (which breaks a bunch of stuff). Does anyone know how to fix this and make the parameter persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The code is rendering raw anchor `<a>` tags to navigate between pages, which when clicked make a page request to the server and reloads the page, i.e. the entire app is remounted. React state only exists in memory, so upon a page reload it goes away unless you are persisting and re-initializing it from localStorage.

## Solution

1. Use the `Link` component from `react-router-dom` to link between pages so the page/app isn't reloaded/remounted.
2. Lift the `BrowserRouter` higher in the ReactTree so that the `Link` component is rendered within a routing context.
3. Use the `useLocation` hook to read the `search` string.

Example:

```
import {
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link,
  useLocation,
  useRouteMatch,
} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Company() {
  const { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  const { search } = useLocation();

  const [lookupData, setLookupData] = useState();

  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
  const ticker = searchParams.get("ticker");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getLookupData(ticker)
      .then(({ data }) => { // <-- destructure `data` property
        setLookupData(data);
      });
  }, [ticker]); // <-- add missing dependency
  
  return lookupData ? (
    <>
      <h2>{lookupData.title}</h2>
      <ul class="leftNav">
        <li class="mainList">
          <Link to={`${url}/Overview`}>Overview</Link>
        </li>
        <li class="mainList">Financials</li>
        <li class="indentList">
          <Link to={`${url}/KeyFinancials`}>Key Financials</Link>
        </li>
        <li class="indentList">
          <Link to={`${url}/IncomeStatement`}>Income Statement</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="body">
        <Switch>
          <Route path={`${path}/Overview`}>
            <Overview cik={lookupData.cik} />
          </Route>
          <Route path={`${path}/KeyFinancials`}>
            <KeyFinancials cik={lookupData.cik} />
          </Route>
          <Route path={`${path}/IncomeStatement`}>
            <IncomeStatement cik={lookupData.cik} />
          </Route>
          <Redirect exact from={path} to={`${path}/Overview`} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </>
  ) : "waiting for lookup data";
}
```

```
<BrowserRouter>

  ...

  <Company />

  ...

</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Using the useLocation and getting the search string was super helpful!